# Convert web folder to self-contained file for offline browsing

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Say, I made a web page which contains js, css and image files. All of them reside in a folder. Is there any proven way to convert the whole folder into a self-contained file(can be html or anything a browser can open)? I'm wondering if such solution already exists.

Please note that I am already aware of 'Save Page' feature in browsers which saves the page and the other content in a separate folder.

Comment: "Save Page as MHTML " setting in about:flags, an official firefox addon does the same in FF. sometimes you can press [CTRL]+[A], copy, and paste into a contenteditable div to inline all the css into html style attribs.

Comment: about:flags is showing up as invalid for me. However mhtml format led me to the right direction. Can you type up something about web archive files and I will accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a browser add-on called "Save Page WE".  Works on Firefox and Chrome.

Firefox add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/

Chrome add-on: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof

Saves the entire contents of a page as a single self-contained `.html` file.  Perfect for archiving web pages for posterity

Answer (score 0):

> made a web page which contains js, css and image files
>   ... [is there a] way to convert the whole folder into a self-contained file?

I would recommend you try an HTML / Web Page / eBook Compiler.  These programs were developed in the late 90s / early 2000s and designed to do exactly what you are asking; compile your HTML page(s) into a stand-alone file (though sadly these programs only work on Windows).

Hit the search engines and try search terms such as:

- HTML Compiler
- eBook Compiler
- Web Page Executable

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single web page I'd just save it as a PDF. Is there a compelling reason not to?

(I may be stating the obvious, but sometimes the simplest solutions are overlooked).